# System of equation left aligned

Tags: equations, align

There is a system of equation.
How to align it on the left? (second line should be started right under the first line)
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fyg9r.png]

My code of this:

```
$\begin{equation}
\left\{\begin{aligned}
\hat a \sum x^2_i + \hat b \sum x_i = \sum x_i \cdot y_i,\\
\hat a \sum x_i + n \cdot \hat b =\sum y_i.\\
\end{aligned}
\right.\end{equation}$
```

Comment: Put the `&` character before the first `\hat` at each line and remove the `$` symbols.

Answer (score 9):

Just use the `cases` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools} 

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{dcases}
  \hat a \sum x^2_i + \hat b \sum x_i = \sum x_i \cdot y_i,\\
  \hat a \sum x_i + n \cdot \hat b =\sum y_i.
\end{dcases}
\end{equation}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It work properly, but now it system looks smaller than another text. Look at the screenshot http://s27.postimg.org/rboabhkyb/Screen_Shot_2014_12_14_at_01_00_44.png. (equation number 5 uses cases). How fix it?

Comment: @0x1337 Load `mathtools` instead of `amsmath` and use `dcases`.

Comment: @Manuel: forgot that size inside cases is like inside array. Corrected.

Comment: @Ox1337: Manuel gave the fix. See my updated answer. Don't load `amsmath` in that case, since `mathtools` does it for you (as a rule of thumb, one should load mathtools rather than amsmath).

Answer (score 3):

Use the & symbol before each expression.
For example to align:

```
\begin {aligned}
\sum^{n}_{i=1} K=0\\
a^2+b+c=0\longrightarrow\Psi 
\end{aligned}
```

Which is:

[image: unaligned]

Use & at the beginning to align them left:

```
\begin {aligned}
&\sum^{n}_{i=1} K=0\\
&a^2+b+c=0\longrightarrow\Psi 
\end{aligned}
```

And obtain:

[image: left aligned]

Or use it before whathever you want, for example before the = to align them:

```
\begin {aligned}
\sum^{n}_{i=1} K&=0\\
a^2+b+c&=0\longrightarrow\Psi 
\end{aligned}
```

Giving:

[image: = aligned]

Comment: The term "before each expression" is not unambiguous since you haven't made clear what you mean by expression. Using an expression [!] such as "at the start of both rows" would be clearer. Better yet, just post a code example that incorporates your suggestion, and all guesswork is eliminated.

Comment: You're right, I'll edit.